# Motd not changing

Tags: ubuntu, motd

My /etc/motd file is showing duplicate messages. When I edit it manual, it keeps returning to the messed up version whenever a user logs in.
How do I stop this? I'm using Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MOTD is generated by a script. To prevent the default MOTD from reverting, remove the execute bit from the `/etc/update-motd.d/00-header` file and put your desired MOTD text into `/etc/motd.tail`. Or, to keep the default MOTD text and just append your own text to it, leave the `00-header` file alone and add your text to the `motd.tail` file.

Comment: Thanks - the duplicate message was in motd.tail - changing it fixed the issue

Answer (score 7):

By default, in recent releases of Debian and Ubuntu (including yours), `/etc/motd` is a symbolic link to `/var/run/motd`, which is regenerated at each login by the [`update-motd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/update-motd.5.html) framework.

If you want a static `/etc/motd` remove a symbolic link and create a regular file in its place. Or you can edit the [`pam_motd`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_motd.html) calls in `/etc/pam.d/*` and pass `motd=/etc/motd.dougk`.

The underlying issue is probably due to some breakage in `/etc/update-motd.d/*`, possibly a backup file duplicating the effect of the corresponding main file.

Comment: How this helped me fix it: I commented out one of the `pam_motd` lines in `/etc/pam.d/` and now I'm back to a single MOTD. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To contribute with a more updated answer:

/etc/motd is no longer a symlink as of Ubuntu 16.02. In debian it is just a regular file.

pam_motd calls all scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d` with run-parts to populate `/var/motd.dynamic`

Both `/var/motd.dynamic` and `/etc/motd` are concatenated for MOTD

Details here

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/04/05/customize-your-motd-login-message-in-debian-and-ubuntu/